# Video clip only imports first image in sequence

Tags: image, movie-clip-editor

When using the Movie Clip Editor and trying to import a sequence of images only the first image is included.

In image 1 you can see I have selected all the images
[image]

In image 2 you see I only have Frame 1 of 1   (1/1)
There should have been 81 images imported

[image]

Why am I not getting the rest

Comment: It looks to me like you are importing the images as video clips instead. If you are doing so, Blender thinks each frame is a video.

Comment: I am following the steps in this YouTube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InIuTtt7W3E&t=424s.  He takes the video clip. saves the individual frames as images and then imports them in a new video clip editor.  The reason he does this is to reset the frame rate.  The only thing I changed was selecting only a small portion of the video clip I want to work with.  I think you are right, but what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question in case anyone else runs across this problem, was the sort order of the images

Image 1 shows I clicked on the display icon 
Then I changed the display mode from sort by date to name of the images.
Not sure why date order did not work, but because it was in the wrong sequence only one image was imported.
[image]

In image 2 you can see all 81 frames (1/81) were imported. Compared to my original post where it showed only 1/1 frames

[image]

Comment: Nice! Always good to find the answer to your own question!

Comment: Probably would be good try to post as a bug. Or as "papercut" on RightClick  site. Thisd doesn't seem like expected behaviour.

Comment: I don't know how to do that.  And someone at my skill level should probably not be posting bug issues.  If someone with a higher skill level wants to confirm this issue and determine that in fact it is a bug that would be better validation.